# JavaCard store (Secret) Data

Tags: java, memory, storage, store, javacard

Setup:
NXP SmartCard with JavaCard 2.2.2

I want to store a wrapped keypart and a pem File on a smartcard in a secret manner. 
But I am wondering if it's possible to store this kind of files or at least their binary Data as bytestreams. I found the FileSystem Class in an old document but that seems to be gone in JavaCard 2.2.2.
Is there any possibility to store data in a safe manner?

Comment: Encrypt it and store it in a plain (persistent) byte array?

Answer (score 3):

Keys and other sensitive data should always be stored in either Java Card `Key` objects or `PIN` objects. The operating system ensures the best integrity of this kind of secret data. Keys should never be stored in plain byte arrays.

PEM is just a format. If it represents a key store it in a `Key` object; if it represents a certificate, you can store it in a plain byte array. Certificate data is not sensitive.

There is no filesystem implementation in the Java Card runtime; you have to build your own.

Comment: thanks, I will try that and report back. I have to talk to our Architect what kind of data we will have.

Comment: Is it right, that an AES Key stores a maximum of 16 Byte or 128 bit? Asking myself how I should store 4096 bit... creating 32 keys?

Comment: You store every key in its corresponding object. Use AESKey only for AES keys. You probably are looking for RSAPrivatKey or RSAPublicKey